# Can someone help me remember the name of this movie? It's not a typical time travel or a black hole movie. More like a virtual reality thing

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

So I saw this romance + drama movie about six months ago (although I think it was released in 2015 as a Hollywood film) where a girl studies in college and falls in love with a boy. They're initially happy but start having relationship troubles after they meet the boy's parents.

The girl is good at physics and she finds out there's this drug (that her professor had created while looking for ways to time travel as he himself had lost his family) that lets you virtually go back in time to fix things. But it lets you do so only in the mind not in reality. So nothing changes in reality no matter what you try. She takes this drug multiple times without telling anyone and in tries multiple ways to fix her relationship but can't. Each time something tears them apart.

She falls super ill at the end because of continued use of the drug but her professor admits her to a hospital to get better.

Comment: Could you possibly mention when you watched it, whether is was Hollywood? Etc.

Comment: It was about 6 months back but the movie was released sometime around 2015. Watched it online. It was hollywood, yes.

Comment: This reminds me of *The House on the Strand*, same premise of mental time travel through a drug administered by a professor, an inability to actually change anything, and the obsession and the effects of the drugs causing great illness. But the only film adaptation I've found is older, it's a male protagonist, and he goes to the 14th century.